# Does Marvel/Disney have film rights to the Human Torch android?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, captain-america

In *Captain America: The First Avenger*, we see in the Stark Expo a reference to 'Phineas T. Horton's Synthetic Man'.  In Marvel comics, this was the original Human Torch.

[image]

Does Marvel actually have the rights to this character, or was this kind of a cheeky nod to Chris Evans playing a Human Torch?

Comment: Doubtful if anyone has seriously considered a *second* Human Torch as a  something to be developed further. The android has gone  through several evolutions and changes in the comics. I suspect it was just an easter egg in CA:TFA.

Comment: I *believe* Fox has the rights to the *name* Human Torch so it would be a real battle to get a **second** flying burning man on the screen in direct competition. Plus...it would confuse audiences..and studios hate that.

Comment: Well this question is now moot with the Disney acquisition of Fox.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All signs point to Marvel owing the rights. During the late 1960's, Marvel staged a brief revival of the character in [Fantastic 4 Annual #4](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Fantastic_Four_Annual_Vol_1_4), allegedly to prevent the creator (Carlos Burgos) from regaining the copyright, indicating that they at least valued it slightly.

> In fact, Burgos’s claims may have never made it to court; his dark
> ritual on that summer day may have instead been reaction to a new
> Marvel comic book. In early August, Lee and Kirby’s Fantastic Four
> Annual #4 featured Burgos’s original Human Torch, battling the new
> teenage Human Torch and the rest of the Fantastic Four. **Cover-dated
> October 1968, it appeared exactly twenty-eight years after Marvel
> Comics #1-in other words, exactly as the initial twenty-eight-year
> copyright was expiring. The original Torch had been revived just long
> enough to ensure their copyright claim-only to be killed again, pages
> later.** “Well, let’s face it,” mused the Thing when Burgos’s creation
> had been extinguished, “ya win a few . . .’n ya lose a few!” Lee had
> Johnny Storm, the last Human Torch standing, eulogizing his fallen
> predecessor this way: “He tried to defeat me . . . and yet, I can’t
> find it in my heart to hate him!”
>
> <sub><sup>[When Carl Burgos tried to sue for the Human Torch](http://www.comicsbeat.com/when-carl-burgos-tried-to-sue-for-the-human-torch/)</sup></sub>

[image]

More recently (in 2014) the Human Torch android was featured in [All New Invaders](http://marvel.com/comics/issue/48355/all-new_invaders_2014_2), presumably to prevent the image and naming rights from reverting to the creator's estate and possibly coming into conflict with the existing (and more popular) Johnny Storm 'Human Torch'.

[image]

---

For the record, the fact that they're the rights-holder doesn't necessarily mean that Marvel haven't come to an agreement with Fox over the use of the name "Human Torch", just that such agreements are usually [shrouded in secrecy](http://www.theverge.com/2016/5/7/11612616/spider-man-captain-america-civil-war-marvel-cinematic-universe). Even if the law favoured them, it seems unlikely that Marvel would risk a multi-million dollar lawsuit (and potentially an injunction against a $100m+ film) just to spite a competitor.